# Is Java foreach iteration order over primitives precisely defined?

Tags: java, foreach, iteration

Example code:

```
int a[] = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3};
int result = 0;
for (int i : a)
    result += i;
```

Is the loop guaranteed to iterate across `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]` in that order? I strongly believe the answer is yes, but [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) seems to not unambiguously state order.

Got a solid reference?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to [the JLS, The enhanced `for` statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#259170), your for-loop is equivalent to

```
int[] array = a;
for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    int i = array[index];
    result += i;
}
```

"where `array` and `index` are compiler-generated identifiers that are distinct from any other identifiers (compiler-generated or otherwise) that are in scope at the point where the enhanced `for` statement occurs." (slightly paraphrasing the variable names here).

So yes: the order is absolutely guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

See [section 14.14.2 of the Java Language Specification, 3rd edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#24588).

> If the type of Expression is a subtype
>   of Iterable, then let I be the type of
>   the expression Expression.iterator().
>   The enhanced for statement is
>   equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>         VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
>    Statement
> }
> ```
>
> Where #i is a compiler-generated
>   identifier that is distinct from any
>   other identifiers (compiler-generated
>   or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3)
>   at the point where the enhanced for
>   statement occurs.

Answer (score 5):

It states in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) that:

```
for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
```

is equivalent to

```
T[] a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = a[i];
        Statement
}
```

Comment: For those confused/unfamiliar as I was by the label syntax "L1: L2: ... Lm", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710422/please-explain-the-usage-of-labeled-statements

Answer (score 1):

I did not find anything in the page you've referenced that would imply out-of-order iteration. Can you post the specific quote?

In any case, I find that this code:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    double a[] = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    int result = 0;
    for ( double i : a ) {
        result += i;
    }
```

decompiles to old-style looping:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double a[] = {
            0.0D, 1.0D, 2D, 3D
        };
        int result = 0;
        double ad[];
        int k = (ad = a).length;
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            double i = ad[j];
            result = (int)((double)result + i);
        }
    }
```

Of course, that's not the same as a guarantee, but at the very least out-of-order iteration over an array would be very weird and would seem to go against obvious common-sense implementation.

Comment: It could be faster to split the elements and thread the loop. Some compilers already unroll and vectorize loops doing math. That is out of order. Threads could be the next thing.