# JavaScript's Statement Performance Questions

Tags: javascript, performance

Can you guys help me determine the performance difference of each of these
statements? Which one would you use?

1. Making a new Array using

   ```
   - var new_list = new Array();  //or
   - var new_list = [];
   ```
2. Appending element using

   ```
   - push('a')
   - new_list[i]; (if i know the length)
   ```
3. Ternary operator  or   `if() {} else (){}`
4. Trying to make isodd function, which is faster

   ```
   (! (is_even)) or (x%2!=0)
   ```
5. `forEach()` or normal iteration

one more

6. `a= b = 3;` or `b=3; a=b;`

[edit: I'm making a Math Library. So any performance hacks discussions are also welcome :) ]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I prefer using 'var myArray = [];' because it's simpler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance characteristics for all browser (especially at the level of individual library functions) can vary dramatically, so it's difficult to give meaningful really meaningful answers to these questions.

Anyhoo, just looking at the *fast* js engines (so Nitro, TraceMonkey, and V8)

1. `[ ]` will be faster than `new Array` -- `new Array` turns into the following logic

   1. `cons` = lookup property "Array", if it can't be found, throw an exception
   2. Check to see if `cons` can be used as a constructor, if not: throw an exception
   3. `thisVal` = runtime creates a new object directly
   4. `res` = result of calling `cons` passing `thisVal` as the value for `this` -- which requires logic to distinguish JS functions from standard runtime functions (assuming standard runtime functions aren't implemented in JS, which is the normal case).  In this case `Array` is a native constructor which will create and return a new runtime array object.
   5. if `res` is undefined or null then the final result is `thisVal` otherwise the final result is `res`.  In the case of calling `Array` a new array object will be returned and `thisVal` will be thrown away

   `[ ]` just tells the JS engine to directly create a new runtime array object immediately with no additional logic.  This means `new Array` has a large amount of additional (not very cheap) logic, and performs and extra unnecessary object allocation.
2. `newlist[newlist.length] = ...` is faster (esp. if newlist is not a sparse array), but push is sufficiently common for me to expect engine developers to put quite a bit of effort into improving performance so this *could* change in time.
3. If you have a tight enough loop there may be a very slight win to the ternary operator, but arguably that's an engine flaw in the trival case of `a = b ? c : d` vs `if (b) a = c; else a = d`
4. Just the function call overhead alone will dwarf the cost of more or less any JS operator, at least in the sane cases (eg. you're performing arithmetic on numbers rather than objects)
5. The `foreach` syntax isn't yet standardised but its final performane will depend on a large number of details;  Often JS semantics result in efficient looking statements being less efficient -- eg. `for (var i in array) ...` is vastly slower than `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) ...` as the JS semantics require `in` enumeration to build up a list of all properties on the object (including the prototype chain), and *then* checking to make sure that each property is still on the object before sending it through the loop.  Oh, and the properties need to be converted from integers (in the array case anyway) into strings, which costs time and memory.

Answer (score 5):

I've always assumed that since (x&1) is a bitwise operation, it would be the fastest way to check for even/odd numbers, rather than checking for the remainder of the number.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you code a simple script like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  // Test your code here.
}
```

You can benchmark whatever you want that way, possibly adding timing functions before and after the `for` statement to be more accurate.

Of course you'll need to tweak the upper limit (1000 in this example) depending on the nature of your operations - some will require more iterations, others less.

Comment: I've done this before, and I've got a few tips.  First, test in multiple browsers, as they have different JS engines.  Second, you'll need more than 1000 iterations to see any results.  And third, you will have to disable script warnings on browsers like IE.

Comment: Also, each browser tracks time differently (incorrectly). Like, I heard that there are cases when IE will ignore times less than 15ms.

Answer (score 3):

1. Both are native constructors probably no difference.
2. push is faster, it maps directly to native, where as [] is evaluative
3. Probably not much of a difference, but technically, they don't do the same thing, so it's not apples to apples
4. x%2, skips the function call which is relatively slow
5. I've heard, though can't find the link at the moment, that iteration is faster than the foreach, which was surprising to me.

Edit: On #5, I believe the reason is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660097/is-java-foreach-iteration-order-over-primitives-precisely-defined), in that foreach is ordered forward, which requires the incrementor to count forward, whereas for loops are ever so infinitesimally faster when they are run backward:

```
for(var i=a.length;i>-1;i--) {
    // do whatever
}
```

the above is slightly faster than:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: You must be like this javascript ninja. Number 5 is the most shocking. are there any other performance hack that you suggest.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty straightforward as to why, you need to evaluate a.length for each iteration, whereas with the first you only grab it the initial go and test against zero.

Comment: A for #5, there's another alternative based on your first example: var l = data.length; for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) { //wee } , I think it's is a bit more logical.

Comment: +1 to Maiku Mori comment. Having a.length inside the for() is only required if you're adding / removing items from the array. If not, just grab it once outside then compare to that value.

Comment: you can put that in one line though: for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i) {...} -- i find this style helps you communicate the scope in which the length variable is being used.

Comment: Also for each iteration in JavaScript is not like the foreach iterators in PHP or C#. It iterates all the properties of an object. So using it for arrays is a really really bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "it iterates all the properties of an object"? And if you can't use it for arrays, what is it there for?

Comment: @Calvin: it behaves like for(in) enumeration, only instead of return the property name it returns the property value.  The semantics for this style of iteration actually require a lot of work (see my for..in comments below).  For objects it's useful, for arrays it works, but is slower than necessary

Answer (score 1):

As other posters suggest, I think doing some rough benchmarking is your best bet... however, I'd also note that you'll probably get very different results from different browsers, since I'm sure most of the questions you're asking come down to specific internal implementation of the language constructs rather than the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

This page says push is slower.
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2