# Please explain the usage of Labeled Statements

Tags: java, break, continue, labeled-statements

- Is breaking and continuing the only uses of labeled statements in Java?
- When have you used Labeled Statements in your programs?

*Sorry the code snippet has been deleted. I am splitting the question*

Comment: Note that this example hardly justifies the use of a label. Python avoids labels and gotos altogether  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-in-python

Comment: Exactly how does Python's lack of labels and gotos relate to the question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### [JLS 14.7 Labeled statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

(edited for clarity)

> *Statements* may have label prefixes (*Identifier* : *Statement*). The *Identifier* is declared to be the label of the immediately contained *Statement*.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no `goto` statement; identifier statement labels are used with `break` ([§14.15](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.15)) or `continue` ([§14.16](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.16)) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

So the JLS is clear that labels are used with `break` or `continue`, and no other grammatical element of the Java programming language uses it.

Strictly speaking, `break` and `continue`, labeled or not, are *NEVER* necessary. They can always be written out of the code. Used idiomatically, however, they can lead to more readable code.

---

Here's an illustrative example: given an `int[]`, we want to :

- print `"One (1)"` on `1`
- print `"Two (2)"` on `2`
- print `"Zero "` on `0`
- immediately stop processing on any other number

  ```
  int[] arr = { 1, 2, 0, 1, -1, 0, 2 };
  loop:
  for (int num : arr) {
      switch (num) {
      case 1:
          System.out.print("One ");
          break;
      case 2:
          System.out.print("Two ");
          break;
      case 0:
          System.out.print("Zero ");
          continue loop;
      default:
          break loop;
      }
      System.out.print("(" + num + ") ");
  }
  // prints "One (1) Two (2) Zero One (1) "
  ```

Here we see that:

- The different numbers are processed in a `switch`
- Unlabeled `break` in the `switch` is used to avoid "fall-through" between cases
- Labeled `continue loop;` is used to skip post-processing on `case 0:` (the label is not necessary here)
- Labeled `break loop;` is used to terminate the loop on `default:` (the label *is* necessary here; otherwise it's a `switch break`)

So labeled `break`/`continue` can also be used outside of nested loops; it can be used when a `switch` is nested inside a loop. More generally, it's used when there are potentially multiple `break`/`continue` target, and you want to choose one that is not immediately enclosing the `break`/`continue` statement.

---

Here's another example:

```
    morningRoutine: {
        phase1: eatBreakfast();
        if (grumpy) break morningRoutine;
        phase2: kissWife();
        phase3: hugChildren();
    }
    http://stackoverflow.com is the best website ever!
```

Here's another case of a labeled `break` being used not within an iterative statement, but rather within a simple block statement. One may argue that the labels lead to better readability; this point is subjective.

And no, the last line DOES NOT give compile time error. It's actually inspired by [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) Puzzle 22: Dupe of URL. Unfortunately, the puzzle does not go into "proper" use of labeled statements in more depth.

Comment: last line actually does give a compiler error as-is. If you add any statement after it it works, because you have to label something for it to be valid.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `break` and `continue` are the only two uses for labeled statements in Java.  (Java has no `goto` statement.)

You can use a label to break out of nested loops.

```
outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            continue outer;
        } // end of inner loop
        System.out.println("outer"); // Never prints
    }
System.out.println("Good-Bye");
```

When you `continue` back to the `outer` label, you're skipping the remainder of both the inner and the outer loop, including the print statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
```