# http: in main method - why no errors? Strange behaviour

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[])  
{
    http: //vk.com
    System.out.println ("Hello world");
}
```

I'm wondering why this code doesn't throw any exceptions or errors. Can you provide me any documentation, that explains this case? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["loop:" in Java code. What is this, why does it compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please explain the usage of Labeled Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710422/please-explain-the-usage-of-labeled-statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is valid because:

- `http:` is a label, that can be used with `break` and `continue` statements.
- `//vk.com` is a comment.

The rest is ordinary, valid Java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The body of the method parses as a labeled statement.

```
  http:       <-- label
  //vk.com    <-- comment
  System.out.println ("Hello world");  <-- statement
```

In this case the label is redundant, but if the statement was (for example) a loop, then you could use a `break http;` statement to break the loop.

For example

```
some_label: for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
                   if (something(i, j)) {
                       break some_label;
                   }
                }
            }
```

Statement labels are so rarely used in Java, that a lot of programmers don't know what they mean.  That is (IMO) a good reason not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a label called `http`. It is useless here but legal.

See [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 0):

This syntax:

```
whatever:
```

creates a *label* named *whatever*.
It is usually meant to be used to control the loop flow, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430977/655027) answer.

Java does reserve the `goto` keyword as well, but is not used.

This is then followed by a comment:

```
//vk.com
```

which has no reason to do anything.